# adding a constraint to a column referenced to another table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have table1 with a column name ID, and I have table2 with the column name ID. Id column in table one is a primary key but in the second table it is not, however I want to add a contraint to table1.ID column not to accept values other thatn table2.ID. Is this possible or not? IF so, how can this be done in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ...
You must make an one to many realtionship - FOREIGN KEY constraint.

You do this by making an ALTER statement. It can be done IF no constraints are violated

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of creating a foreign key relationship:

```
create table Table1 (id int primary key)
create table Table2 (id int foreign key references Table1(id))
```

In database design, it's called a "one-to-many" relation between Table2 and Table1.  One row in Table1 can relate to many rows in Table2.  A row in Table1 can relate to only one row in Table2.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a contraint to table1.ID
>   column not to accept values other
>   thatn table2.ID
>
> Id column in table one is a primary
>   key

This is only possible to do with a foreign key constraint if ID column in Table2 is defined as unique or is the primary key.

This will work:

```
create table Table2 (id int unique)
create table Table1 (id int primary key foreign key references Table2(id))
```

This will also work:

```
create table Table2 (id int primary key)
create table Table1 (id int primary key foreign key references Table2(id))
```

This does not work:

```
create table Table2 (id int)
create table Table1 (id int primary key foreign key references Table2(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You refer the First Table Column "ID" as a Foreign Key to the Second Table.